# How to tick 'checkbox' in IE using VBA?

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, checkbox, automation

I need to tick a checkbox using vba on a certain website.
I have tried several methods, however without any luck so far.

It is impossible to inspect this element (checkbox) by clicking right mouse button on it, because if you click left/right mouse buttons - checkbox becomes checked.
In order to identifty the element, I have click CTRL+SHIFT+C and found out responsible piece of code for it.

I have tried to locate this element by:
1) It's class, then tried to use '.click' or '.checked = true' methods,
2) `.getAttribute("onmousemove"...)`
3) `.getAttribute("ontouchstart"...)`

However none of those worked.
There was no error, however the checkbox was not ticked.

I have found out that when you move your mouse over the checkbox - it's style is being changed to: "height: 19px; cursor: pointer

```
         <tr ontouchstart="Grids[0].ARow=Grids[0].Rows[&quot;1_1&quot;];Grids[0].ASec=0;"
 onmousemove="Grids[0].ARow=Grids[0].Rows[&quot;1_1&quot;];Grids[0].ASec=0;"
 class="GODataRow  GOClassChanged" style="height: 19px;"></tr>
```

I expect the checkbox to be checked.

Comment: The code you had shown is only for table row. Please try to post the code for that checkbox too. Does that checkbox has any ID or class or any specific text? If yes than try to find it using that text and try to click it may help.

Comment: Hi Deepak-MSFT,
That is the whole problem. That specific checkbox does not have any id, name, etc.
You cannot even examine this element, because clicking right or left mouse button makes the checkbox 'ticked'.
I have pressed CTRL+SHIFT+C, went into Dev. Mode and found out that responsible code for this checkbox is the one posted above, and:

<td style="background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);" class=" GOClassEdit GOClassChangedCell GOClassFocusedCell GOBool1 GOCell GOEmpty HideCol0Select" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
You cannot examine checkbox - you can examine the area that surrounds it

Comment: I don't think If you try to click on row using class or events than it will work because same class and events used by many other elements on the page. We need to reference this checkbox in VBA code to click on it. If it is possible for you than you can try to share the URL of the page. We can try to check it to get more idea about the issue.

Comment: That's the problem. I am not able to share the website as it can be used only by employees in my office. This is the first time I am encountering such issue. In most cases I just locate element by name, text, ID, or if there is a javascript function responsible for triggering the element - then I locate the element by specific attribute and then do the .FireEvent <function>. However this one is tricky.

Comment: Without any testing it would be difficult for us to provide any solid suggestion which can fix the issue.

Comment: Have you tried finding the element in the html by searching via attributes? Your posted code, as @Deepak-MSFT says, is for a tr, but your comment code is for a td.    More HTML would definitely help.